# What is the maximum number of node types in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How many node types can we have under one single Service Fabric? Is 3 the maximum? Can we have more than 3? In the portal we can set a max of 3 node types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arm template to have more node types than 3. I never read about the node type limit anywhere, I assume there is one, but its probably to big to be of a concern

We are using 4 node types (under same SF cluster), for example, we could go for more, but we dont need more.